# Referencing two entities in a @Where clause in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, filter, where-clause

I have the following Entity in my application:

```
    @Entity
    public class A implements Serializable {
        ...
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "thread", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
        private List<B> comments;
        ...
```

When I get any instance of the entity A, I have to get a sublist of B depending on some complex conditions. I have tried using a @Where clause like this:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "thread", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Where(clause = 
     "CASE " +
     " WHEN moderationType = 'PRE' AND state = 1 THEN 1" +
     " WHEN moderationType = 'POST' AND state IN (0,1,4) THEN 1" +
     " ELSE 0" +
     " END = 1 "
    )
    private List<B> comments;
```

The problem I have is that this condition involves not only the B entity, but also A (attribute moderationType belongs to A and attribute state belongs to B). When I try to get any A entity, I get the following error because attribute moderationType does not belong to B:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00904: "B2_"."MODERATIONTYPE": invalid identifier
```

Is there any way to reference both entities (parent and referenced) in a @Where clause?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You might be better looking at using a Filter: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment Alan. I am afraid Filters does not solve my problem because I still have to use fields from another table in my query.

Comment: @Genzotto Did you get any answer for your question?